# Add title attribute to the Winter Bash icon on the top bar

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2015, top-bar, winter-bash

The ***title*** I meant in the ***title*** was the HTML attribute ***title*** and not the ***title*** of the event.

The winterbash icon appears next to the inbox and the reputation icons

[image: icon]

The inbox has a tool-tip. The rep box also has a tool-tip. Why doesn't the poor hatbox have a tool-tip.

[image: No title]

For the sake of uniformity, can we have a tool-tip for the hatbox also?

Something like -  ***Recent hats earned***

Comment: Just realized that the *Stack Overflow Careers* link at the bottom of the page also doesn't have a title!!!

Comment: It's a surprise! Click it!

Comment: @Kristján My momma always said "Life was like a box of hats, you never know what you're gonna get."

Comment: @DamienH Hat's what she said!

Comment: @Kristján I imagine that pun would bowler over.

Comment: @DamienH And usually her jokes are so deadpanama

Comment: @Kristján So much so I can hardly beret.

Comment: @DamienH Last time I kept at this, someone beanied me with a tomato

Comment: I know votes on meta are different, but can anyone explain why they don't like the idea of adding title attribute?

Comment: Because they want you to win the Amazing Grace hat...

Comment: Probably because it's a very minor change to a feature that will disappear in about 2 weeks.