# Tooltip is missing on Winter Bash menu

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, tooltips, winter-bash-2017

A tooltip is missing on the Winter Bash menu:

[image: Screenshot of menu bar]

### Source Code:

We are missing the `title` attribute in the `anchor` tag:

[image: Screenshot of HTML code]

### Solution:

Kindly add the `title` attribute to the **Winter Bash** `anchor` tag:

```
<a **title="Winter Bash"**  class="-link icon-winterbash" href="#">....<a>
```

Answer (score 7):

Good catch – added. Thanks!

Comment: looks like you missed it 2 years back https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312782/add-title-attribute-to-the-winter-bash-icon-on-the-top-bar ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao Well, better late than never ;p